# How to get Selenium IDE to work on Firefox 32

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I just installed the Selenium IDE plugin into Firefox 32 using the "Get Add-ons" feature.  When I click on the Selenium button, I get an alert box that says: "You don't have installed Selenium IDE".

Has anyone else ever encountered this problem, and if so, do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bro please do not add selenium addon from firefox as there is selenium IDE 1.2.0 available
as this is a bug in firefox 32, so you have to manually download the addon for firefox 32
go to this website: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and download Selnenium IDE 2.8.0 version , it will work.Apart from that if you have more questions please write it down on the same thread, i will be very happy to answer them.

Comment: Thanks Monis, that solved the problem. It's working perfectly now.