# How to get Selenium IDE to work on Firefox 45

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-ide

I have the same problem as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637529/how-to-get-selenium-ide-to-work-on-firefox-32) thread, the only difference is that I use firefox 45 instead of 32. I have performed the same solution by manually downloading the add-on instead but it still does not work. I still get the javascript alert of "You don't have installed Selenium IDE".

Downgrading to firefox 32 is not an option, is there another way to come around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find below steps to download Selenium IDE which also worked in my case in Firefox version(44.0.2) ::

1. Visit https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/
   on your Mozilla browser.
2. Then Click on "Add to FIrefox" button you find on your page.
3. After getting downloaded click on install and then soon after
   restart now.
4. Then you will find Selenium IDE button on the top right hand side of
   the browser and also you can find the same under Tools section in
   Browser Menu.

Hope it will help you :)